# couchdb having trouble querying by a specific key or value

Tags: curl, couchdb, nosql

Currently, my database has three documents, and it looks like this:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[

{"id":"hello-world","key":"2009/01/15 15:52:20","value":"Hello World"},
{"id":"biking","key":"2009/01/30 18:04:11","value":"Biking"},
{"id":"bought-a-cat","key":"2009/02/17 21:13:39","value":"Bought a Cat"}

]}
```

I want to query by the specific value "Biking" using the following command:

```
C:\Users\Alex>curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/alex/_design/example/_view/byDate?value="Biking"
```

This should return the only row with the value "Biking" but instead it returns the same result as shown above. I am doing all this on Windows. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Views are indexed by `key` field, it's not possible to query them by `value` one. In your case you need to create another view where data from `value` field would be emitted as keys.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/alex/_design/example/_view/byName?key=""Biking""
```

P.S. Also note, that `key` query parameter should contains valid JSON value, so on Windows, you need to set double quotes around the key parameter.

Comment: Oooo yea, I remember now. But I've tried querying by the key, and using double quotes and I get an error..I  believe because there are spaces in my date string..How do I escape space characters in Windows?

Comment: Not sure since I hadn't Windows right by now to test, by try to wrap whole url with quotes like: `"http://127.0.0.1:5984/alex/_design/example/_view/byName?key=""foo bar"""`. Also, url escaping via `%20` should works.

Comment: So it works when I add the two extra quotes around the string and url, and add %20 in place of the the space between the date and time.  The output says "{"total_rows":3,"offset":1,"rows":[ " Do you understand why the total number of rows is 3 even though there's only one row in the query result?

Comment: `total_rows` is the total amount of rows in view without applying any filtering conditions. `offset` means the position from the beginning where the result rows starts from.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. I do not want to start a new topic, since this question will be related to CouchDB as well. So I will be doing a presentation on CouchDB, which is a relatively new topic to me. As I was researching on this topic, I've come across the following quote, "The major benefit of using a document database comes from the fact that while it has all the benefits of a key/value store, you aren’t limited to just querying by key." So can you give an example in CouchDB where this applies?

Comment: Oh, that's a wide topic. Could we move this discussion to the CouchDB [user mailing list](http://couchdb.apache.org/#user-mailing-list)? There you could receive community-powered answer on this question, not personal mine (: